# design a sampling mechanism to guarantee approximated correctness

Tags: optimization, sampling

Given a function $f: X \to \mathbb{R}$ with some discrete domain $X$,  $|X| = 2^n$. The cardinality of the domain is expontential.

Our objective is to find $\textbf{argmax}_{x \in X} f(x)$. Which can not be solved via broute force.

But we have a probabilistic sampling mechanism that is able to return $x $ with probability $P(x)$.

I'm wondering how can I design a sample and then stop mechanism to ensure the approximated maximum with a probabilistic guarantee.